# select two random and consecutive rows from grouped data

Tags: r, dplyr

In the data below (included with `dput`), I have repeat observations (lat and long) for three individuals (IndIDII). Note, there are a different number of locations for each individual and that they are arranged by `IndYear`.

```
  IndIDII      IndYear  WintLat  WintLong
1 BHS_265 BHS_265-2015 47.61025 -112.7210
2 BHS_265 BHS_265-2016 47.59884 -112.7089
3 BHS_770 BHS_770-2016 42.97379 -109.0400
4 BHS_770 BHS_770-2017 42.97129 -109.0367
5 BHS_770 BHS_770-2018 42.97244 -109.0509
6 BHS_377 BHS_377-2015 43.34744 -109.4821
7 BHS_377 BHS_377-2016 43.35559 -109.4445
8 BHS_377 BHS_377-2017 43.35195 -109.4566
9 BHS_377 BHS_377-2018 43.34765 -109.4892
```

I would like to `filter` and make a new `df` that has two consecutive rows for each `IndIDII`. In my larger data set, all individuals have at least 2 observations (i.e. rows), with a range of 2 to 4 observations per individual. Obviously, for individuals with only 2 rows, the code will return the only 2 rows available. With more data, rows 1 and 2, **or** 2 and 3, **or** 3 and 4 would be randomly selected. The order of the rows is not important so long as they are consecutive (i.e. could return 3 and 4 **or** 4 and 3).

As always, many thanks!

```
Dat <- structure(list(IndIDII = c("BHS_265", "BHS_265", "BHS_770", "BHS_770", 
"BHS_770", "BHS_377", "BHS_377", "BHS_377", "BHS_377"), IndYear = c("BHS_265-2015", 
"BHS_265-2016", "BHS_770-2016", "BHS_770-2017", "BHS_770-2018", 
"BHS_377-2015", "BHS_377-2016", "BHS_377-2017", "BHS_377-2018"
), WintLat = c(47.6102519805014, 47.5988417247191, 42.9737859090909, 
42.9712914772727, 42.9724390816327, 43.3474354347826, 43.3555934579439, 
43.3519543396226, 43.3476466990291), WintLong = c(-112.720994832869, 
-112.708887595506, -109.039964727273, -109.036693522727, -109.050923061224, 
-109.482114456522, -109.444522149533, -109.45659254717, -109.489241553398
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ave`. Within each group, create a row index (`i <- seq_along(x)`). To get the first index of rows to keep, sample one row from all but the last row index (`sample(head(i, -1), 1)`. Include also the next row (`+ 0:1`). Check which row indices are in the sampled rows (`i %in% ...`). Coerce result back to logical to subset data.

```
Dat[as.logical(ave(Dat$IndIDII, Dat$IndIDII, FUN = function(x){
  i <- seq_along(x)
  i %in% (sample(head(i, -1), 1) + 0:1)
})), ]

#   IndIDII      IndYear  WintLat  WintLong
# 1 BHS_265 BHS_265-2015 47.61025 -112.7210
# 2 BHS_265 BHS_265-2016 47.59884 -112.7089
# 4 BHS_770 BHS_770-2017 42.97129 -109.0367
# 5 BHS_770 BHS_770-2018 42.97244 -109.0509
# 7 BHS_377 BHS_377-2016 43.35559 -109.4445
# 8 BHS_377 BHS_377-2017 43.35195 -109.4566
```

In a similar vein, but more succint, with `data.table` and its builtin row index (`.I`) and number of rows per group (`.N`)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(Dat)
Dat[Dat[ , (sample(.I[-.N], 1)) + 0:1, by = IndIDII]$V1]
```

Comment: @B. Davis Please note the small tweek of the `data.table` alternative, using `.N` instead of `head(...`. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution using R base functions

```
> set.seed(505) # you can set whatever seed you want, I set 505 for reproducibility
> lapply(split(Dat, Dat$IndIDII), function(x) {
  ind <- sample(nrow(x))
  cons <- if(ind[1] < max(ind)){
    c(ind[1], ind[1]+1)
  } else {
    c(ind[1], ind[1]-1)
    }
  x[cons, ]
})

$`BHS_265`
  IndIDII      IndYear  WintLat  WintLong
1 BHS_265 BHS_265-2015 47.61025 -112.7210
2 BHS_265 BHS_265-2016 47.59884 -112.7089

$BHS_377
  IndIDII      IndYear  WintLat  WintLong
6 BHS_377 BHS_377-2015 43.34744 -109.4821
7 BHS_377 BHS_377-2016 43.35559 -109.4445

$BHS_770
  IndIDII      IndYear  WintLat  WintLong
3 BHS_770 BHS_770-2016 42.97379 -109.0400
4 BHS_770 BHS_770-2017 42.97129 -109.0367
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly clunky tidyeval way. Could definitely be improved (what if you want more than 1 consecutive?) but works for this application. You can also remove the row column with a `select()` at the end of the function.

```r
Dat <- structure(list(IndIDII = c("BHS_265", "BHS_265", "BHS_770", "BHS_770", "BHS_770", "BHS_377", "BHS_377", "BHS_377", "BHS_377"), IndYear = c("BHS_265-2015", "BHS_265-2016", "BHS_770-2016", "BHS_770-2017", "BHS_770-2018", "BHS_377-2015", "BHS_377-2016", "BHS_377-2017", "BHS_377-2018"), WintLat = c(47.6102519805014, 47.5988417247191, 42.9737859090909, 42.9712914772727, 42.9724390816327, 43.3474354347826, 43.3555934579439, 43.3519543396226, 43.3476466990291), WintLong = c(-112.720994832869, -112.708887595506, -109.039964727273, -109.036693522727, -109.050923061224, -109.482114456522, -109.444522149533, -109.45659254717, -109.489241553398)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))

library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
sample_2_consecutive <- function(tbl, group_col){
  group_col <- enquo(group_col)
  with_rownums <- tbl %>%
    group_by(!!group_col) %>%
    mutate(row = row_number())
  rows_to_keep <- with_rownums %>%
    filter(row != max(row)) %>%
    sample_n(1) %>%
    mutate(row2 = row + 1) %>%
    gather(key, row, row, row2)
  with_rownums %>%
    semi_join(rows_to_keep, by = c(quo_name(quo(!!group_col)), "row")) %>%
    arrange(!!group_col, row) %>%
    ungroup() # %>%
  # select(-row)
}
sample_2_consecutive(Dat, IndIDII)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   IndIDII IndYear      WintLat WintLong   row
#>   <chr>   <chr>          <dbl>    <dbl> <int>
#> 1 BHS_265 BHS_265-2015    47.6    -113.     1
#> 2 BHS_265 BHS_265-2016    47.6    -113.     2
#> 3 BHS_377 BHS_377-2017    43.4    -109.     3
#> 4 BHS_377 BHS_377-2018    43.3    -109.     4
#> 5 BHS_770 BHS_770-2016    43.0    -109.     1
#> 6 BHS_770 BHS_770-2017    43.0    -109.     2
```

Created on 2018-09-27 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).