# Select random consecutive rows by group as a proportion of group length

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Assuming I have a time series with different groups with various group length. How can I randomly select consecutive rows by group and as a function of each respective group length (e.g. 10 % of each group)

I tried it by using [code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546036/select-two-random-and-consecutive-rows-from-grouped-data) - but it does not work with my data.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# Creating a dummy dataframe:
cell <- c(rep("a", 100), rep("b", 80),  rep("c", 60),  rep("d", 40),  rep("e", 20), rep("f", 10))
df <- data.frame(cell) %>% group_by(cell) %>% mutate(Time = row_number()) %>% as.data.table()

df_subset <- df[df[ , (sample(.I[-.N], 1)) + (0:(0.1*.N)), by = cell]$V1]
```

The issue with the subset:

- It does not take the proportion somehow as the amount of selected rows does not fully reflect the group length (I expect, 10,8,6,4,2 and 1 samples)
- A bigger issue is that for bigger proportions it actually samples outside of the length of each group. E.g. if it selects row 99 for a row length of 100, every random sampling above 2 creates NAs in my dataframe.

I wrote my own function at the end - but I wonder if there is a nice dplyr or data.table way of handling this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
df[df[ , {
    k = ceiling(0.1 * .N)
    sample(head(.I, -k), 1L) + (0L:(k-1L))
}, cell]$V1]
```

Idea is to pick an sample from the index vector, but the sample must be at least k spaces away from the end of the vector so that if we happen to pick the kth element from the back, we will use the kth to last element from the back. To do this we use `head(.I, -k)`.

`head(.I, -k)` remove the last k indices. `sample(..., 1L)` randomly picks an element and since when we need k elements, we choose this picked element and the subsequent k-1 elements.

Comment: Would you elaborate why we use head(.I, -k), 1L) and -k?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a user-defined function that does consecutive random sampling, and then use it with `dplyr`:

```
consecutive_subset <- function(x, prop) {
  i_start <- sample(1:(length(x)-floor(length(x)*prop)), 1)
  i_end <- (i_start+floor(length(x)*prop)-1)
  return(x[i_start:i_end])
}
```

This function returns a random sample of consecutive elements of a vector `x`, with the sample length determined as a proportion of `length(x)` (e.g. "10% of each group" as in your question). If `length(x)` isn't evenly divisible by `prop`, the length of the sample length is floored to avoid errors. This function also shouldn't sample outside the boundaries of `x`, given its definition.

You can then group your data, and apply this function to each column of each group with `summarise_all`:

```
result <- df %>%
  group_by(cell) %>%
  summarise_all(~ consecutive_subset(., 0.1))
```

Checking that the length of each subset is correct using `summarise(result, n())`, you get:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  cell  `n()`
  <chr> <int>
1 a        10
2 b         8
3 c         6
4 d         4
5 e         2
6 f         1
```

Comment: That works nicely - and I solved it also with my own function. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The adjusted function I used to solve it was from the link above:

```
df_subset <- df[as.logical(ave(df$cell, df$cell, FUN = function(x){
  i <- seq_along(x)
  i %in% (sample(head(i, -(length(i)*0.25)), 1) + 0:((length(i)*0.25)-1))
})), ]
```

Of note - if the column is a factor you need to use `as.character()` for the respective column (df$cell here).