# Select Random Consecutive Rows Per Group

Tags: r, sequence

I have data which is grouped by 'student_id':

```
my_data = data.frame(student_id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
                     exam_no = c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),
                     result = rnorm(15,60,10))


my_data
   student_id exam_no   result
1           1       1 56.60374
2           1       2 55.76655
3           1       3 53.81728
4           1       4 74.82202
5           1       5 34.91834
6           2       1 58.32422
7           2       2 60.38213
8           2       3 49.40390
9           2       4 63.85426
10          2       5 40.32912
11          3       1 69.54969
12          3       2 43.36639
13          3       3 37.97265
14          3       4 52.36436
15          3       5 61.62080
```

**My Question:**

For each student, I want to select a set of *consecutive* rows, with *random* start and end rows.

For example, keep exams 2-4 for student 1, keep exams 2-5 for student 2, etc.

---

I thought of the following way to do this:

Create a data frame that contains the max number of exams each student takes (in my problem, each student takes the same number of exams, but in the future this could be different)

```
library(dplyr)
counts = my_data %>% group_by(student_id) %>% summarise(counts = n())

# create variables that indicate where to start ("min") and where to end ("max") for each student
counts$min = sample(1:counts$counts, 1)
counts$max = sample(counts$min:counts$counts,1)
```

From here, I was then going to write a loop that would select rows between "min" and "max" index for each student (e.g. my_data[min:max]), but the results from the previous code are giving me warnings and illogical results:

```
Warning message:
In 1:counts$counts :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used

Warning messages:
1: In counts$min:counts$counts :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
2: In counts$min:counts$counts :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used

# A tibble: 3 x 4
  student_id counts   min   max
       <dbl>  <int> <int> <int>
1          1      5     4     5
2          2      5     4     5
3          3      5     4     5
```

I am not sure how to continue this - can someone please show me how to continue?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you always need multiple row per group? Student 1 has 5 rows. In your attempt, if the min row was 5 for student 1, there are no more rows left to sample. Is that okay? Or do you need the method to get at least 2 rows per student? What distribution of number of row per student would you like? If we continue with your method - randomly pick a start and end row - you will tend to pick more rows from students with more data.

Comment: Alternately, you could do something like (a) pick a start row and then (b) pick a number of rows to sample from that start row. That would let you easily do something like "pick 3, 4, or 5 random rows from each student" - though depending on how concerned you are about bias it could prefer later row to earlier rows...

Comment: Related: [select two random and consecutive rows from grouped data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52546036/select-two-random-and-consecutive-rows-from-grouped-data) (disclaimer: I apparently also answered it... ;); [selecting n randomly sampled consecutive rows across all levels of a factor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836875/selecting-n-randomly-sampled-consecutive-rows-across-all-levels-of-a-factor-with), but with a fixed sample size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`, within each group, sample two values from `.I` (without replacement), and create a sequence of indices.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)

set.seed(3)
my_data[my_data[ , {ix = sample(.I, 2); ix[1]:ix[2]}, by = student_id]$V1]

#   student_id exam_no   result
#         <num>   <num>    <num>
# 1:          1       5 74.05672
# 2:          1       4 49.37525
# 3:          1       3 67.41662
# 4:          1       2 67.64935
# 5:          2       4 55.15337
# 6:          2       3 58.95694
# 7:          3       4 50.79859
# 8:          3       3 53.66886
# 9:          3       2 47.01089
```

Answer (score 3):

A base R option using `cumsum` to label the in-between consecutive rows

```
subset(
  my_data,
  ave(
    exam_no,
    student_id,
    FUN = function(x) cumsum(seq_along(x) %in% sample.int(length(x), 2))
  ) == 1
)
```

which gives, for example

```
   student_id exam_no   result
2           1       2 61.83643
3           1       3 51.64371
4           1       4 75.95281
6           2       1 51.79532
7           2       2 64.87429
8           2       3 67.38325
11          3       1 75.11781
12          3       2 63.89843
13          3       3 53.78759
```

---

A more compact version by `data.table` with a similar idea as above is

```
library(data.table)
setDT(my_data)[, .SD[cumsum((1:.N) %in% sample.int(.N, 2)) == 1], student_id]
```

Comment: @ ThomasIsCoding: Thank you for your answer! can you please explain this code - is it selecting a random consecutive sample from each student?

Comment: @stats_noob yes, a random consecutive sample from each student. It first generates two random positions and the indices in between is the desired.